# Does linking to sister websites help or hurt SEO?

Tags: ranking

I have a traveling website, so I want to discuss some issues which I am facing on the website. The problem is that the website keywords ranking is at the top of the search engine for the previous month, but now all the keywords are not in rank in the search result on google.

My website has a sister website too, and it has social links, google my business account is present on the sister website.

so can you tell me, does it affect my website?

I need some expert advice, on how can I go ahead with this situation.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.